# Python: loop through list item x times?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python2.7 and I would like to loop through a list x times.

```
a=['string1','string2','string3','string4','string5']
for item in a:
  print item
```

The above code will print all five items in the list, What if I just want to print the first 3 items? I searched over the internet but couldn't find an answer, it seems that xrange() will do the trick, but I can't figure out how.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Sequence Slicing](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html) is what you are looking for. In this case, you need to slice the sequence to the first three elements to get them printed.

```
a=['string1','string2','string3','string4','string5']
for item in a[:3]:
      print item
```

Even, you don't need to loop over the sequence, just [join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) it with a newline and print it

```
print '\n'.join(a[:3])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works and sequence slicing can also be used to slice a list of tuples too, such as a=[('string1','string2'),('string3','string4'),('string5','string6')]

Comment: @michelle26: `sequence slicing can also be used to slice a list of tuples too...`, was it a question or a statement ?

Comment: you'll need to flatten that list if you want to join it up

Comment: Thanks Abhijit,that's not a question, I am so glad that sequence slicing can do lots of useful tasks

Comment: @Wim: I am not sure, I understood what you are trying to imply. The List is already flattened, you just need to pass it through a `str.join`

Comment: @Abhjit I was talking about the list of tuples in the comment above, not the list in the original question

Answer (score 6):

I think this would be considered *pythonic*:

```
for item in a[:3]:
    print item
```

**Edit**: since a matter of seconds made this answer redundant, I will try to provide some background information:

**Array slicing** allows for quick selection in sequences like Lists of Strings. A subsequence of a one-dimensional sequence can be specified by the indices of left and right endpoints:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4,5][:3] # every item with an index position < 3
[1, 2, 3]
>>> [1,2,3,4,5][3:] # every item with an index position >= 3
[4, 5]
>>> [1,2,3,4,5][2:3] # every item with an index position within the interval [2,3)
[3]
```

Note that the left [endpoint is included](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29), the right one is not. You can add a third argument to select only every `n`th element of a sequence:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4,5][::2] # select every second item from list
[1, 3, 5]
>>> [1,2,3,4,5][::-1] # select every single item in reverse order
[5,4,3,2,1]
>>> [1,2,3,4,5][1:4:2] # every second item from subsequence [1,4) = [2,3,4]
[2, 4]
```

By converting lists to [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) arrays, it is even possible to perform multi-dimensional slicing:

```
>>> numpy.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]])[:, ::2]
array([[1, 3, 5],
       [1, 3, 5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=['string1','string2','string3','string4','string5']
for i in xrange(3):
    print a[i]
```